# tracking origin of symbols in shared libraries

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, elf, dynamic-linking

I have a shared library (more specificly a native python module) which references some symbols from other libraries. `ldd -r` displays which symbols of the library can't be resolved dynamically on the system. example:

```
# ldd -r /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/_selinux.cpython-34m.so
…
undefined symbol: selabel_digest        (/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/_selinux.cpython-34m.so)
```

Now I have a similar system where the linking seems to work, ldd doesn't report any unresolved symbols.
**How can I track how and from which sources (filename of the shared library) certain symbols are resolved on that system?** I hope this might help me to get the linking on the first system correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I track how and from which sources (filename of the shared library) certain symbols are resolved on that system?

On the "working" system, run

```
LD_DEBUG=symbols,bindings ldd -r _selinux.cpython-34m.so |&
grep selabel_digest
```

Comment: Thanks.
Just for further reference: Seems like [man 8 ld-linux](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux) was the place to look for, I only consulted the binutils ld docs.